# Scala SBT and JNI library

Tags: scala, java-native-interface, sbt, leveldb

I am writing a simple app in `Scala` that uses a leveldb database through the `leveldbjni` library. My `build.sbt` file looks like this:

```
name := "Whatever"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.iq80.leveldb" % "leveldb-api" % "0.6",
    "org.fusesource.leveldbjni" % "leveldbjni-all" % "1.7"
)
```

An `Object` is then responsible for creating a database. Unfortunately if I run the program I get back a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`, raised by the `hawtjni` library that `leveldbjni` exploits under the hood.

The error can be triggered easily also from the scala console:

```
scala> import java.io.File
scala> import org.iq80.leveldb._
scala> import org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory._
scala> factory.open(new File("test"), new Options().createIfMissing(true))

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.init()V
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.init(Native Method)
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.<clinit>(NativeOptions.java:54)
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory$OptionsResourceHolder.init(JniDBFactory.java:98)
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.open(JniDBFactory.java:167)
    at .<init>(<console>:15)
...
scala> System getProperty "java.io.tmpdir"
res2: String = /var/folders/1l/wj6yg_wd15sg_gcql001wchm0000gn/T/
```

I can't understand what is going on since the library is getting correctly extracted from the jar file but it is not getting loaded for some reasons.

```
$ file /var/folders/1l/wj6yg_wd15sg_gcql001wchm0000gn/T/lib*
/var/folders/1l/wj6yg_wd15sg_gcql001wchm0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-1.7.jnilib:    Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/var/folders/1l/wj6yg_wd15sg_gcql001wchm0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-1.7.jnilib (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/var/folders/1l/wj6yg_wd15sg_gcql001wchm0000gn/T/libleveldbjni-1.7.jnilib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

I think the problem is probably related to the classloader that sbt employs but I am not sure since I am relatively new to scala.

**UPDATE**

Still didn't find what or who is the culprit. Anyway the library is actually found and correctly loaded, since I can execute the following commands:

```
scalac> import org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB
scalac> NativeDB.LIBRARY.load()
```

The error is somehow due to the `init()` function that according to the `hawtjni` [documentation](http://fusesource.com/forge/sites/hawtjni/documentation/developer-guide.html) is responsible for setting *all the static fields annotated as constant fields with the constant value*. The exception can still be triggered by typing:

```
scalac> import org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions
scalac> new NativeOptions()
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.init()V
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.init(Native Method)
    at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.<clinit>(NativeOptions.java:54)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
```

Comment: What is the content of the system property `java.library.path`? Have you tried to set this property to the path where the extracted libraries are?

Comment: Yes already tried that by using all the possible configuration options. Still the same error

Comment: What OS/JDK versions are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known problem as documented in this [sbt issue page](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/358). I have implemented, according to the [eventsourced documentation](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced/wiki/Installation#wiki-native), a custom `run-nobootcp` command that executes the code without adding the Scala library to the boot classpath.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: On OS X 10.8 with sbt 0.13 and scala 2.10 via MacPorts, I get the problem originally described. SBT Issue #358 indicates this problem should be fixed with sbt 0.13, but that seems not to be the case. The custom run-nobootcp command also doesn't work... but I'm just copying and pasting without real understanding.

Interestingly, using leveldbjni from within a Play project works great.

Comment: I am actually using scala 2.10 and sbt 0.13 on OSX 10.8.5 without any problems now, by using a `run-nobootcp` task. Are you sure that you are following the instructions correctly?

Comment: I am not at all sure, no, being a Scala noob. leveldbjni _does_ work fine within a Play app context, though, so that is good enough for the time being.