# UnsatisfiedLinkError with native library under sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 0.13 and have issues using the [leveldbjni](https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni) native library under sbt (even after [issue #358](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/358) has been resolved). A [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750780/scala-sbt-and-jni-library) has already been reported for which sbt 0.13 should provide a solution but it seems it doesn't. So I'm sharing my observations here.

I'm getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with the following example application.

- build.sbt

  ```
  name := "example"

  version := "0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

  libraryDependencies += "org.fusesource.leveldbjni" % "leveldbjni-all" % "1.7"
  ```
- build.properties

  ```
   sbt.version=0.13.0
  ```
- Example.scala

  ```
  import org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal._

  object Example extends App {
    NativeDB.LIBRARY.load() // loading succeeds 
    new NativeOptions() // UnsatisfiedLinkError under sbt
  }
  ```

I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7 and OS X 10.8.5. Running the example with `run-main Example` under sbt gives

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeOptions.init()V
```

whereas running it with

```
java -cp scala-library.jar:example_2.10-0.1.jar:leveldbjni-all-1.7.jar Example
```

just works fine. The application even runs successfully when Scala is on the bootclasspath:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:scala-library.jar -cp example_2.10-0.1.jar:leveldbjni-all-1.7.jar Example
```

Any ideas why there's an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` only under sbt?

Comment: This is just a workaround, but have you tried [forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html)?

Comment: @gourlaysama yes, with forking it actually works but, as you said, it's just a workaround. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I should also add that the forking workaround only works with sbt 0.13, not with earlier versions.

Comment: Sbt is using magic classloaders to try to prevent "leaks" of native loaded libraries, and allow you to re-import the library multiple times.   Sbt will actually rename the DLL/SO/jnilib and load it in a special classloader.   I'm not positive if this is only a plugin feature, or something for all apps.

Where I've seen this in the past is when not using this functionality and having my native library already linked on another classloader.   Does this happen on every run, or only after a successful run?

Comment: @jsuereth This happens on every run.

Comment: Martin did you manage to solve this issue ?  I am working with akka persistence and i am having the same error

Comment: @integratingweb fork your tests (recommended) or set akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native=off (works without forking but should be used only for testing)

Comment: It may be of some help - https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced/wiki/Installation#wiki-native.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski thanks, but I'm the author of this Wiki page :) This page is also linked in the sbt issue #358 linked above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Any ideas why there's an UnsatisfiedLinkError only under sbt?

As @juereth commented:

> Sbt is using magic classloaders to try to prevent "leaks" of native loaded libraries, and allow you to re-import the library multiple times. Sbt will actually rename the DLL/SO/jnilib and load it in a special classloader. I'm not positive if this is only a plugin feature, or something for all apps.

So this is somewhat expected behavior with the current design of sbt. If forking works, then that's what you have to do.